# Pokemon Go login issues

Tags: pokemon-go

I just dowloaded pokemon go and when i try to login with my google account  there is a screen that comes up saying "Our servers are humbled by your incredible response. We are working to resolve the issue. Please try again later, and when i restart the game it still comes up even if i come back a day later and i try to login.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as annoying as it is, it's fairly normal these days when the game is getting released to more and more countries.

You can keep trying to log in or just follow some of these community pages to get notified when server issues are fixed.

https://twitter.com/PokemonGoApp
https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4t5pfd/server_status_and_known_issues_faq/